# sbt [error] No valid parser available

Tags: scala, sbt

I am running:

> java -version
>   java version "1.8.0_121"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

sbt 0.13.13.

on Windows 10.

When I follow the tutorial to do a println("hello"), I get the error:

[error] No valid parser available.

Do you guys have any idea why that might be and how to resolve?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Double check the structure of your project. I'd guess something is not set up quite right. See this answer for a bare bones `sbt` project to get going: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42708227/390708

Answer (score 8):

You entered into the [sbt shell](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Interactive-Mode.html), which is used to give commands for a project build.

It sounds like you want a Scala console. You can start it by:

```
sbt console
```